# Emit socket events only to a set of clients in a room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am building a real-time application with node and socket io.

My questions are :

On my client side I have

```
socket.emit('adduser', username);
```

On my server side I have

```
socket.on('adduser', function(username) {
 io.sockets.in(socket.room).socket.emit('user-added', somedata);
}
```

And now again coming to the client side I have a user-added listener

```
socket.on('user-added', function(somedata) {
// get shit done!
}
```

Now assume I have 3 clients connected and all of them share the same scripts.
According to my understanding of socket io when I say  `io.sockets.in(socket.room).socket.emit` the event is going to emit to all the connected clients in the particular room.

Say for example, I only want client 1 and client 3 to listen to this `'user-added'` event

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to emit to all users in the same room, then you can use the following to emit to a particular client based on his id.

```
io.sockets.socket(socketid).emit('user-added', {data: yourData});
```

Comment: yea but socket(socketid) will emit only to a particular socket. Say if there are 3 clients in the room, I want to emit to client 1 and client 3

Comment: Well It seems you don't want to emit to the socket who emitted, Like client 2 is the emitting socket and client 1 and 3 are the other two connected sockets to the same room, If so then you can use 'socket.broadcast.to(socket.room).emit('user-added', {data:yourData});'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to emit to all users except to the sender, you can use the following code:

```
socket.broadcast.to('room1').emit('new user');
```

If you instead want to emit to all users including the sender, the following code will do:

```
io.sockets.in('room1').emit('new user');
```

Note that you don't need the `socket` call after `io.sockets.in()`.